# Listen to click event on Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

How to listen to click event on the component and call a method on the component?

Ex -

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div>Hello my name is {{name}}. </div>
   `
})
export class MyComponent {
  name = "Aj"
}
```

**HTML -**

```
<my-component></my-component> // user clicks here
```

Now how do I listen to click on the component itself?

Answer (score 32):

Use `HostListener` in your component. The answer given by Ploppy works, but Angular tells you to use `HostListener` in your component instead like this

```
import { HostListener  } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  [...]
})
export class MyComponent {

  @HostListener("click") onClick(){
    console.log("User Click using Host Listener")
  }

}
```

Comment: But how do you get the coordinates of the mouse click?

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Back in the day the documentation was lacking.

Comment: @CodyBugstein You do this by passing a second argument to `@HostListener` that represents the parameters passed to the listening function. Thus, to get the `Event` object, do: `@HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(event: MouseEvent) { ... }` (see [here](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener#args))

Answer (score 9):

**Update: Rahul Singh has the right answer**

---

Use the `host` property of the `@Component` decorator:

```
@Component({
  ...,
  host: { '(click)': 'onClick()'}
})

export class MyComponent {
  private onClick() {
    console.log('onClick');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The same way as you monitor for a click anywhere, with the (click)="myFunction" syntax.

The details can be found here at the Angular docs.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding

When you say "on the component itself", if you mean that you don't want the parent element listening for the click, then simply put the (click) handler in your component template instead of the parent's  tag. In this scenario, the parent will be unaware of the captured click.